# Starting a Java Spring Web MVC app: no mapping found

Tags: java, spring, jsp, maven, spring-mvc

Every time I try to visit http://localhost:8080/hello/?name=test, I receive the following problem:

> WARNING: No mapping found for HTTP request with URI
>   [/views/helloworld.jsp] in DispatcherServlet with name 'dispatcher'

Here's how my directory structure looks:

```
├── pom.xml
└── src
    └── main
        ├── java
        │   └── dnss
        │       └── DNSS.java
        ├── resources
        └── webapp
            ├── index.jsp
            ├── views
            │   └── helloworld.jsp
            └── WEB-INF
                ├── dispatcher-servlet.xml
                └── web.xml
```

pom.xml:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>dnss</groupId>
    <artifactId>dnss</artifactId>
    <packaging>war</packaging>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>

    <properties>
        <spring.version>4.1.4.RELEASE</spring.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <version>3.8.1</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-dependency-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.3</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <phase>package</phase>
                        <goals><goal>copy</goal></goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <artifactItems>
                                <artifactItem>
                                    <groupId>org.mortbay.jetty</groupId>
                                    <artifactId>jetty-runner</artifactId>
                                    <version>7.5.4.v20111024</version>
                                    <destFileName>jetty-runner.jar</destFileName>
                                </artifactItem>
                            </artifactItems>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

web.xml:

```
<web-app id="WebApp_ID" version="2.5"
         xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee
                 http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd">

    <display-name>DNSS</display-name>

    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>

    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>

    <context-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>/WEB-INF/dispatcher-servlet.xml</param-value>
    </context-param>

    <listener>
        <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
    </listener>
</web-app>
```

dispatcher-servlet.xml:

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
       xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xsi:schemaLocation="
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.0.xsd">

    <context:component-scan base-package="dnss" />

    <bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
        <property name="prefix" value="/views/" />
        <property name="suffix" value=".jsp" />
    </bean>
</beans>
```

and helloworld.jsp:

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=utf-8" pageEncoding="utf-8"%>
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Spring MVC Tutorial</title>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>Hello : ${name}</h1>
</body>
</html>
```

And DNSS.java:

```
package dnss;

import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.ui.Model;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestParam;

@Controller
public class DNSS {

    @RequestMapping("/hello")
    public String hello(@RequestParam(value="name", required=false, defaultValue="World") String name, Model model) {
        model.addAttribute("name", name);
        return "helloworld";
    }

}
```

I'm not sure what's wrong... everything seems to be correct, but for some reason it just can't find my /views/helloworld.jsp file when it's pretty obvious that it exists. Can someone point me to the right direction?

Comment: To access the controller method the mapping should be only /hello. For example localhost:8080/<project root>/hello.

Comment: i guess your url is like `http://localhost:8080/hello?name=test` and you got to remove the `*`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay this was a bit silly; I noticed from the code block on StackOverflow that my url-pattern was commenting out everything... so I removed the * and it's showing the page now.